# Modify line by line of .txt using .bat

Tags: batch-file

I have this `.txt` file:

```
Previsto:  R$ 9.766,53  
Previsto:  R$ 423,65  
Previsto:  R$ 514,51  
Previsto:  R$ 492,63
```

**So i need change the word "Previsto" to another word, like it:**

```
Visa: R$ 9.766,53

Elo: R$ 423,65

Hipercard: R$ 514,51

Sorocred: R$ 492,63
```

I did this `.bat` script:

```
@echo off 
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion
    set "search=%Previsto"
    set "replace=%Visa"
    set "textFile=extract.txt"

    for /f "delims=" %%i in ('type "%textFile%" ^& break ^> "%textFile%" ') do (
        set "line=%i"
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        >>"%textFile%" echo(!line:%search%=%replace%!
        endlocal
    )
```

But all line are replacing "Previsto" to "Visa"
I don't know how to set it to change only the fisrt line to "Visa" the second line "Elo", thrid "Hipercard", etc.

How can i do it?

Thanks

Comment: where to take all those words from? Do you have a text file with them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this :

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "$file=extract.txt"
set "$search=Previsto"

set $repl[1]=Visa
set $repl[2]=Elo
set $repl[3]=Hipercard
set $repl[4]=Sorocred

set $count=1

(for /f "delims=" %%a in (%$file%) do (
   call:replace "%%a" !$count!
   set/a $count+=1
   )
)>out.txt

echo done..
exit/b

:replace

set "$line=%~1"
set $repl=!$repl[%2]!
set "$line=!$line:%$search%=%$repl%!"
echo !$line!
```

The ouput file is `out.txt`

**Edit 2**

for the blank line after line 1

```
:replace

set "$line=%~1"
set $repl=!$repl[%2]!
set "$line=!$line:%$search%=%$repl%!"
echo !$line!
if "%2"=="1" echo.
```

Comment: I can't save the <out.txt> in '%userprofile%/Desktop/' why?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar idea as SachaDee but a different approach on creating an array
and without a subroutine

```
:: Q:\Test\2018\06\04\SO_50684988.cmd
@Echo off&SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

Rem Set replace[0..3] to cards
Set i=-1&Set "replace= Visa Elo Hipercard Sorocred"
Set "replace=%replace: ="&Set /a i+=1&Set "replace[!i!]=%"

set "search=Previsto"
set "textFile=extract.txt"
set /A "cnt=pnt=0,i+=1"

(for /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %%A in ('type "%textFile%" ') do (
  if /i "%%A" equ "%search%" call Echo=%%replace[!pnt!]%%:%%B
  if !pnt!==0 Echo=
  Set /A "cnt+=1,pnt=cnt %% i"
) ) >"New_%textFile%

type "New_%textFile%"
```

Sample output with a blank line following visa:

```
>SO_50684988.cmd
Visa:  R$ 9.766,53

Elo:  R$ 423,65
Hipercard:  R$ 514,51
Sorocred:  R$ 492,63
```

The batch would replace any number of Previsto in turn with the replacements.